# Refresh custom object's related list in Lightning from custom lightning component on click of popup save(communities Builder)

Tags: lightning, related-list, experience-builder-page

I am trying to refresh the custom object related list(dragged into the panel in builder ), this has to happen on click of popup save which is in custom lightning component placed above the related list in lightning builder,i am not looking for browser refresh, please help.

Note: I have tried using $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();  in side SUCCESS state in custom lightning component still not working..

Thanks..